# Set string in URL (Reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Example, when I use the link:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809
```

It automatically converts to:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster...
```

How to do the same thing in Reactjs? (I already have a string inside my Component)

Comment: It's temporary redirect in server level. In react: `window.location.href = window.location.href + '/string-that-you-already-have'`

Comment: You can refer the ```window.location.href``` explanation here https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_get_url.asp, Also you can refer here for more documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Comment: @Justinas not sure that this is the way to go in a React context tbh, at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer:

```
  const { id } = useParams(); // get id by react-route
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    let exampleName = "string-by-id";  // get string name by id 
    history.push("/questions/"+id+"/"+exampleName);
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 2):

Generally:

To redirect the client (that is, to basically simulate them clicking a link), use `window.location.href = 'my-domain/my-subdirectory'`.

To replace the client's URL (that is, to redirect them without adding the current URL to the browser history), use `window.location.replace('my-domain/my-subdirectory')`.